# One Image not showing in Android, IE7, IE8, everywhere else fine

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I'm testing a Wordpress site I've built, a problem I have is for some reason the Art Below logo which appears just about everywhere else, doesn't show in IE7, IE8 and Android.

Anyone with fresh eyes want to take a look?

Its the footer first logo on the left.

http://www.missingtom.com

Comment: Why the downvote it's a straightforward problem that needs a solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a CMYK jpeg. Convert it to RGB and give it a try if it works.
I tested with IE8/7 and indeed it doesnt's show up, shows a red circle, loads just fine with other browsers.

Edit: Here is RGB version of your file - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BouFz.jpg if you don't know how to do it yourself or you're unable to. Rename it to artbelow.jpg and replace the file on your server (http://www.missingtom.com/wp-content/themes/artwars2/images/artbelow.jpg) make a hard refresh (alt+f5 usually) and see if it shows up.

More info about CMYK and IE (possibly also Android browsers as you stated?... - http://www.plaveb.com/blog/cmyk-images-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try, thanks for stopping and helping...I'll let you know if it works.........

Comment: Ok that worked, thanks, both in IE7/8 and Android.......I didn't know about this before, so thanks for your help.......